# Logical operations involving NA

Tags: r, logical-operators, na, missing-data

Since "is.na(NA)" returns true and "NA > 0" returns NA, "is.na(NA) & (NA > 0)" should return NA which is true.

> is.na(NA) & NA >0
>
> [1] NA

In the same way, "!is.na(NA)" returns false and "NA > 0" returns NA, "!is.na(NA) & (NA > 0)" should return NA as well. But R returns false. Why is this?

> !is.na(NA) & NA >0
>
> [1] FALSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `?"&"`

> NA is a valid logical object. Where a component of x or y is NA, the result will be NA if the outcome is ambiguous. In other words NA & TRUE evaluates to NA, but NA & FALSE evaluates to FALSE. See the examples below.

In the OP's condition, the first one evaluates to

```
TRUE & NA #(is.na(NA)#[1] TRUE;NA > 0#[1] NA)
```

and second is

```
FALSE & NA #(!is.na(NA)#[1] FALSE)
```

Comment: When I use `?&`, it returns the following error: `Error: unexpected '&' in "?&"`. How were you able to get the explanation?

Comment: @user3119750 You can either quote or use backquotes.  I used backquotes, but when I copy/pasted, it got removed